# Using Node Module in Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic2, woocommerce-rest-api

I am learning Angular 2 and trying to build a mobile app using Ionic 2 RC0 which uses Angular 2 and TypeScript. I am trying to use the node module [woocommerce-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api) in my app but I am always getting errors.

I installed the module using npm.

```
npm install --save woocommerce-api
```

Then in my .ts file, I am trying to import it like this,

```
import * as WC from '../../../node_modules/woocommerce-api'
```

Although VS Code does not display any errors but I still cannot get it to use in my methods and constructor.
I don't mind not getting the intellisense help but I just want to make this module work.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: There are no typings available for [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api) module.

Comment: what's the error ? do you use webpack ?

Comment: It is strage that there are no errors during compilation, but you can quickly declare it with `declare var WC: any;`. (And you can use `import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api'`)

Comment: @Julian: I am getting errors during compilation and that is why the `main.js` is not been built. Cannot proceed at all.

Comment: Here is what happens: `import * as WC from "woocommerce-api";` gives me red squiggly line under the module name. `import * as WC from "../../../node_modules/woocommerce-api";` gives no errors but on compilation fails, `Rollup: treating net as external dependency` error.

Answer (score 0):

`net` is a node.js module that is not avalible in the browser, and cannot be found for that reason.
But if you take a look at the repo it is only a simple [wrapper](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-node/blob/master/index.js).

It is the best to create a new service in angular and call the [Api](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) directly with angulars http.

Comment: That would require me to implement OAuth 1.0a also because it is required.

Comment: You can use modules that Support Browsers. But you should not use an auth key from client side. If something like that is needed you have to create an simple node server that returns this type of data